# How to find the call forwarding success or fail from onActivityResult()?

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I have done a sample program to do unconditional call forwarding. This code sets the call forwarding as intended in the phone settings. But how can I find in my app that it successfully done it or not?  Here in `onStart()` I am calling `startActivityForResult()` and based on the RESULT CODE I need to do two different actions (for RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELLED). The problem here is its always setting it to RESULT_CANCELLED irrespective of the case.

```
public class CallForwardFragment extends Fragment {
    static final int CALL_FORWARD_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container,
                false);

        return v;
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        String phoneNumber="9875678956";
        String urls = "tel:" + "**21*" +phoneNumber + Uri.encode("#");
        Intent intentCallForward = (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                    Uri.parse(urls)));
        intentCallForward.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivityForResult(intentCallForward, CALL_FORWARD_REQUEST);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), resultCode + "ResultCode",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (requestCode == CALL_FORWARD_REQUEST) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                session.enableCallForward();
                session.setCallForwardNumber(callFwdPhNum);
                session.setCallForwardChoice(Integer
                        .parseInt(ProfileDetailFragment.callFwdDetailsUtil
                                .getmFwdCondition()));
            } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Always this will be called for both success and fail
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a remark: `RESULT_OK` and `RESULT_CANCELLED` are static fields of `Activity`, so you don't have to call `getActivity()` to access them, just use `Activity.RESULT_OK` or `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible at all at the moment. Look [at this.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285&q=ussd&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)